# Recover files dragged to windows backup

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-7-backup

I have a hard drive where I store my windows backups as well as a few other folders. I was in this folder when I was bumped and it made me drop an entire folder on the windows backup folder and said folder disappeared. When I search the folder for a file included in the folder that was lost, it shows up under

```
E:\Backups\Lost Folder\File
```

However when I try and restore a folder from the backup it only lists the locations that I originally setup for the backups. e.g. C:\ & D:\ but there are not entries for the folder or E:\ which is where it was located. How can I find this missing folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double clicking the backup file opens the windows backup utility and if the files are not located on the drives you are backing up they will not show up. However if you have verified that they are there you can browser there in windows explorer.

Type in `E:\Backups\Lost Folder\` or just `E:\Backups\` to browse any other files stored there.